# "I am prayer" in Psalm 109:4?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms

> "In return for my love they are my adversaries; But I am all prayer."

[Psalm 109:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) JPS 1917

Someone quoted to me the part of this verse which says "I am all prayer". The idea "I am prayer" was used this way:

Suppose I perform an action with Hashem in mind, in obedience to Him, and I do it for Him. This, it was stated, is a nonverbal form of prayer in which my actions communicate to Hashem.

For instance, if I am performing a task at work when no one is watching-- say, cleaning up-- and I choose to do a good job when no one will notice or care, but I do it for Hashem with Him in mind, is that action a form of prayer?

Has anyone heard of this verse being used this way, or are there other sources to support this?

Comment: What does it mean to clean up at work for Hashem?

Comment: There are times at work when my mind is not set on Hashem. In those times I may obey Torah, but I am not actively thinking of Him. But there are other times where I might not say anything, but I intentionally do something with an acknowledgement in my mind of His eye upon me, and I do it so as to show Him love, or reverence, or fear.

Comment: ואני תפילה is often understood to mean that Dovid himself was a prayer, not that he prayed. I think there may be a medrashic source for this.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE the closest I found is the idea that we are reliable in tefilla (Pesikta D'Rav Kahanna 28:9). All the midrashim seem to connect this idea to the idea that despite the fact that the nations hate us, we still offer 70 korbanot on their behalf on Sukkot

Comment: wonder if connected https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.69.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 3):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.4?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Psalms.109.4.2&lang2=bi) explains simply as, that because I always pray to You, I am like a living prayer. So to some degree that falls in with your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what @Dov said, the [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.4?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Ramban%20on%20Genesis%7CQuoting&lang2=en) seems to explain that this means that prayer is his constant occupation. Thus, you are "a man of prayer" [(Shaarei Teshuvah 3:147)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.4?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Shaarei%20Teshuvah&lang2=en). See also the [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.4?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en) there.

Comment: Nice find, this is a very good avenue to follow to find if OP's idea exists and where